# BuildBunderMinifier in .Net Core Auto Build

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, bundling-and-minification

I am building C#/MVC web apps, and have used BundleConfig.cs in past C# MVC .Net Framework projects, using the RegisterBundles library to minify CSS and JavaScript files.  While developing/debugging, it never required me to restart and rebuild the project after CSS or Javascript file changes were made.  Now that I am moving to .Net Core, the [BuildBunderMinifier](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BuildBundlerMinifier/3.2.435/ReportAbuse) NuGet package requires me to stop a project, rebuild, start the project, and force refresh a page every time I make any change in CSS.  Is there any way to make changes in CSS and see the result without having to stop/rebuild/restart every time?

Edit:  Installing BroswerLink does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was easy: Install the [BundleMinifier](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier) extension, in addition to enabling Browser Link.  It was not obvious at first, because after installing BundleMinifier, I had to then select "Update Bundles" from the project's context menu.  After that, the CSS changes were rendered automatically after every save.